# Terminate a thread in java with a little problem

Tags: java, multithreading

The code below is that I try to stop a thread I created without using stop(). However, The thread seems like it would executed once more after it be stopped. I wonder why this happened? Plus: If I change the iteration from 100 to 10, it works without any problems. Can anyone help me with this problem? Thanks in advance!

```
  public class TerminateThread implements Runnable{
    private boolean flag = true;
    public TerminateThread(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    private String name;
    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        while(flag) {
            System.out.println(name+"--->"+i++);
        }

    }
    public void Terminate() {
        this.flag = false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TerminateThread tt = new TerminateThread("Thread");
        new Thread(tt).start();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
            if (i == 88) {
                tt.Terminate();
                System.out.println("Thread terminated!!!");
            }
            System.out.println("main--->" + i);
        }

    }

}
```

The outcome is :
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the thing is, your code doesn't terminate the thread, it simply makes it finish its work at the next iteration.

What could be happening is the flag variable isn't being instantly updated to all threads when changed, and you are setting it with the main thread. To remedy this, declare `flag` as volatile.

`private volatile boolean flag = true;`

More Info:
[What is the volatile keyword useful for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/106591/what-is-the-volatile-keyword-useful-for)

Comment: Still, it could set the terminated flag between the check and the output (which is very likely, if you look what happens on `System.out.println()`)

Comment: Yup, but it looks like OP is showing it happens much later than the set flag call, so it must be the problem of the value not being updated across threads. But I did intend to point that out with the first sentence.

Comment: Locks in java are not fair. It appears that the main thread grabs the lock for the output stream before after releasing it before the second thread grabs it for a while.

Comment: Wouldn't the second thread be waiting on the monitor, and execute next as when the main thread's sout call finishes it releases the lock and calls notify() ?

Comment: You should post an answer if you feel it'll help some people.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn why do you have the same profile description as I do? "SOreadytohelp" eg stack overflow ready to help haha. [so off topic]